# Tkinter use functions/widgets from another class

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm starting with python.
I want to display the keywords_label on Page1 and Page2, when enter is pressed. And I want to switch to Page2, when START is pressed.

Is there a way to use a function in a class from another class? And display a label in multiple Frames?

```
from tkinter import *

class Page(Frame):
 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

 def show(self):
     self.lift()

class Page1(Page):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    # Keywords
    global entry_keywords
    entry_keywords = Entry(self)

    def printKeywords():
        keywords_label = Label(self, text=f'Keywords: {entry_keywords.get()}', pady=1, anchor=W)
        keywords_label.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.2, relwidth=0.5, anchor=NW)

    enter_button = Button(self, text="Enter", padx=10, pady=5, command=printKeywords, borderwidth=1)

    entry_keywords.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.5, height=30, anchor=NW)
    enter_button.place(relx=0.75, rely=0.1, anchor=N)

    start_button = Button(self, text="START", command=Page2().show)
    start_button.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.8, relheight=0.1, relwidth=0.3, anchor=NW)



class Page2(Page):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)


class MainView(Frame):
 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    p1 = Page1(self)
    p2 = Page2(self)

    buttonframe = Frame(self)
    container = Frame(self)
    buttonframe.pack(side="left", fill="y", expand=False)
    container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

    p1.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
    p2.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

    # Buttons for Pages
    b1 = Button(buttonframe, text = "Page 1", command=p1.show)
    b2 = Button(buttonframe, text = "Page 2", command=p2.show)
    b1.pack(side="top")
    b2.pack(side="top")

    p1.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   root = Tk()
   main = MainView(root)
   main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
   root.wm_geometry('600x400')
   root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is actually? If you have already tried something, post it and the full error traceback.

Comment: I reformulated my question, I hope it helps. If I press Start nothing happends.

Comment: When you press `START` button, you create new instance of `Page2` and call it `.show()` function. However the new instance of `Page2` is not put in window using any layout manager, so it is invisible.  Also what you want is to show the instance of `Page2` created inside `MainView` instead, but you need to make it an instance variable otherwise it cannot be accessed outside `__init__()` function.